# Value of Buttons in Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code, at every button click it is replacing the value. But, I want at every click it will give value of button as many as I click. But no replace like when I click it 3 times, it would give 5 5 5 three times in textbox.

```
<script>
    function setText7(obj){
        var val = obj.value;
        console.log(val);
        document.getElementById('textBox').value = val;
    }
</script>
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnSeven" onclick="setText7(this)" name="csv" class="btn" value="5">
<textarea rows="5" name="textBox"  id="textBox" cols="30"></textarea>
```

Comment: You forgot very basic thing.. do like `document.getElementById('textBox').value + = val;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append with previous values, you need to do `document.getElementById('textBox').value + = val;`.

Check this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ws5h0y74/1/

```
function setText7(){
var val = event.target.value;
console.log(val);
document.getElementById('textBox').value += val;
}
```

Comment: Answer was good but here is requirement to add value where the cursor moved.. if I click button it adds value to next to the position. Can It be at where the cursor located,? If i clicked three times is is adding values at next  position but when I move cursor to the first position It should add value at first ..